# Is there any way to call a web service hosted on unsecured subdomain from a secured server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, ssl, https, web-applications

I have hosted a web-app with ssl certified custom domain bought from godaddy. Firebase provided a ssl certificate but when I am trying to call an API hosted over my subdomain without any ssl pointing to an AWS EC2 IP it is returning an 500 error saying not allowed to access unsecured server from a secured server. Is there any way to bypass this policy or any other solution?

Comment: Why not fix the problem? Using HTTP only is a bad idea.

Comment: Agree, Still I want to try out some new things.